# SSRS -External image not rendering on HTML report

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I am working on SSRS Report. I have a report with an external image embedded in it
This renders fine inside the report viewer.

but when I render  report in HTML 4.0 format in my application via web url (without using report viewer).The report that comes back from all the data except the image is not in the html

see the image tag looks like the following:-

```
<img onerror="this.errored=true;" class="r1" src="http://ges-server-pc/ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS?%2FGES-MVC%2FGES_FWCR&amp;rs%3ASessionID=vdpuofii3xtph545xelnym45&amp;rs%3AFormat=HTML4.0&amp;rs%3AImageID=1403af250c474da8a5f851b63a8a377b">
```

how can I render extrenal image on Report  which is in format= HTML 4.0

Can Anybody have solution for the same It will be appreciable

Thanks in advance

Comment: I bet this is a permission issue. You are not authorized to access the resource. It looks like an image from the render stream. How are you authenticating with the report server?

Comment: that is True  I got error in  console as status code 401(Unauthorized).I am authenticating my report using  "CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials"

Comment: Can you explain how you are getting the payload? It sounds like you are authenticating with ssrs with credentials to render then the report comes back as byte[] and you display the report. Inside the payload is a reference to a url back to the report server, however, your authorization to render does not cover your apps need to access the image it created back on the server.

Comment: I am authenticating  SSRS with server credential to render report, then report comes back as  an HTML  in response stream and populate it in my application without using report viewer. It seems me that image in  the rendered html by server has not get permission

Comment: Without having ssrs stream the report images to/from a location that your users have access or without given the application access to rs itself, I don't know the answer. If you find a way to send in a value for DeviceInfo.StreamRoot via url then you may be able to do this via URL access. I will post an answer that I used to get around this. Look it over and if its not something you are willing to undertake or you found a solution for url access then I will delete my answer. Please note that I was using the ssrs api directly and not url access.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to ensure that your application can reliably display images dynamic rendered in a report by SSRS.

When you are using the report viewer control, a lot is done behind the scenes to keep an active session and allow access to all artifacts generated by reports requested by the user. When you are using the ReportExecution api directly there are some advanced reporting features that are just not supported. Interactive sorting, sizing, drilldown and this issue just to name a few.

Always ensuring dynamic images from reports are available to your client is pretty easy. I had to cross this hurdle a way back and I'll share the way I solved it.

In a nutshell, you are going to have to intercept the render, iterate the streams, and save each resource to a temp folder and tell ssrs to look for the image in your temp folder that is behind the web app that your end user has authenticated with.

**DeviceInfo**

The device info structure, mostly overlooked, is going to come in handy. In this structure you will find a **StreamRoot** property. You can find documents on this. It basically allows you to override the location from which SSRS will stream resources as needed. This is how you tell SSRS to look for your external images in a new location.

For each report rendered I create a temp folder using a guid prior to rendering. Also, prior to rendering you need to set the StreamRoot to this temp folder.

```
string physicalTempFolder = MakeNewTempFolderInTempOffOfWebRoot();
string virtualTempFolder = Path.Combine(yourWebRoot,"Temp",Path.GetDirectoryName(physicalTempFolder));
```

Now you have a physical and virtual pointer to your repo where the images will be saved for your report. Now update the StreamRoot in SSRS. This tells SSRS that we want to override the default location for dynamic images and whatnot.

```
StringBuilder devInfo = new StringBuilder();
if (YourRenderFormat=="HTML")
{
    devInfo.Append("<DeviceInfo>");
    devInfo.Append("<StreamRoot>" + virtualTempFolder+ "</StreamRoot>");  
    devInfo.Append("</DeviceInfo>");       
}
```

With the needed device info structure build we can pass it into the render method.

```
string extension;
string mimeType;
string reportEncoding;
string[] streamIDs = null;
ReportExecution2005.Warning[] warnings = null;            

ReportExecution2005.ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ReportExecution2005.ExecutionHeader();
ReportExecution2005.ExecutionInfo rpt = _execService.LoadReport(YourReportPath, null);

if(YourParamas!=null)
    _execService.SetExecutionParameters(YourParams, "en-us");
_execService.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;
_execService.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID = rpt.ExecutionID;

result = _execService.Render(format, devInfo.ToString(), out extension, out mimeType, out reportEncoding, out warnings, out streamIDs);
```

The render method returns the streamIDs out parameter and it is key here. Next after we call render, simply iterate all the streams that are images and call ssrs's `RenderStream()` method to get the images and save to your physical temp folder.

```
if (YourRenderFormat=="HTML"))
{

    string imageEncoding = "";               
    // For each image stream returned by the call to render,
    // render the stream and save it to the application root
    string FilePath = physicalTempFolder;
    byte[] image;
    // For each image stream returned by the call to render,
    // render the stream and save it to the application root
    foreach (string streamID in streamIDs)
    {
        image = _execService.RenderStream("HTML4.0", streamID, null, out imageEncoding, out mimeType);
        //All files are unique
        File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(physicalTempFolder,streamID),image);
    }
}
return result;
```

Comment: Hi @Rosh Bush, Right no I chnaged my logic , I am accessing my report using  web service like ReportexecutionService Class (Render Method)                Html replced the image like this with my folder path                               <IMG onerror="this.errored=true;" onload="this.fitproportional=true;this.pv=0;this.ph=0;" SRC="http://ges-server-pc/ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS?%2FGES-MVC%2FGES_FWCR&rs%3ASessionID=modjz555sgzkf42exfla3mqc&rs%3AFormat=HTML4.0&rs%3AImageID=Report\GraphFiles\8c6c13be-46c7-4db5-9352-14.jpg/>  but still images  not displying on render html report

Comment: If you can verify that the image is being written to a temp folder under your web app then the account associated with the app pool managing your app surely has read access. Can you create a test web page and add a <img src="ges-server-pc/…\GraphFiles\8c6c13be-46c7-4db5-9352-14.j‌​pg"/>. Are you assigning the fully qualified domain name to the StreamRoot?

Comment: thanks for your support...I am new in SSRS.. here is I have posted my  another question related to this issue .here I briefly describe my question with code                   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219831/ssrs-image-not-rendering-on-html-4-0-reportunauthorization