# SSRS -Image not rendering on HTML 4.0 Report(Unauthorization )

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am working on SSRS report. I am accessing report using  web services (using web refrences)
I am using ReportExecutionService class to render report in the html 4.0 format and finaly I attach rendered HTML to my page DIV. Report is rendering very fine in HTML format but the images on that is not rendering properly because of missing authentication for images
 for that  I just replace the src attribute of the img tag in the response returned from the SSRS report execution service with the url to this location below is code for render report:-

```
 public string Render(string reportDirectory,string reportName,string reportFormat, ParameterValue[]parameters )
        {
            _reportServerExecutionService.ExecutionHeaderValue = new ExecutionHeader();
            _reportServerExecutionService.TrustedUserHeaderValue = new TrustedUserHeader();
            _reportServerExecutionService.LoadReport("/GES-MVC/GES_FWCR",null);
            _reportServerExecutionService.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");


            string encoding;
            string mimeType;
            string extension;
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamIds;

            var result = _reportServerExecutionService.Render(reportFormat, @"<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>", out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIds);
            //Here is logic for image replcaement

            string html = string.Empty;
            html = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
            html = GetReportImages(_reportServerExecutionService, _reportServerExecutionService.ExecutionHeaderValue, _reportServerExecutionService.TrustedUserHeaderValue, reportFormat, streamIds, html);


        return html;

    }
```

and function (code) for image replacement

```
   public string GetReportImages(ReportExecutionService _reportServerExecutionService, ExecutionHeader executionHeaderValue, TrustedUserHeader trustedUserHeaderValue, string reportFormat, string[] streamIds, string html)
        {

                if (reportFormat.Equals("HTML4.0") && streamIds.Length > 0)
                {
                    string devInfo;
                    string mimeType;
                    string Encoding;
                    string fileExtension = ".jpg";
                    string SessionId;
                    Byte[] image;

                    foreach (string streamId in streamIds)
                    {
                        SessionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("}", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("-", "");


                        string reportreplacementname = string.Concat(streamId, "_", SessionId, fileExtension);
                        html = html.Replace(streamId, string.Concat(@"Report\GraphFiles\", reportreplacementname));
                        devInfo = "";

                   image= _reportServerExecutionService.RenderStream(reportFormat, streamId, devInfo, out Encoding, out mimeType);

                    System.IO.FileStream stream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Report\\GraphFiles\\" + reportreplacementname);
                    stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
                    stream.Close();
                        mimeType = "text/html";
                    }



            }

            return html;


        }
```

but issue is that  image is saved into folder and also src tag is replaced into html ,still image is not display on report Can anybody have solution for this or any related code for same

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

This is close to being correct. There is one small part you are missing.

Not only do you have to intercept the streams and save each to a temp location that is accessible to your app, you also have to let SSRS know that the renderer should source the dynamic images to your new location.

The way to let the renderer know about the new location is to override the **DeviceInfo.StreamRoot** passed into the `Render()` method.

```
string thisReportInstanceID = Guid.NewGuid();
string thisReportInstanceTempFolder = Path.Combine("Temp",thisReportInstanceID );
string physicalTempFolder = Path.Combine(<YourPhysicalWebRoot>,thisReportInstanceTempFolder );
string virtualTempFolder =<YourVirtualWebRoot>+"/Temp/"+thisReportInstanceID );

Directory.Create(physicalTempFolder );

StringBuilder devInfo = new StringBuilder();
if (format.ToUpper().StartsWith("HTML"))
{
    devInfo.Append("<DeviceInfo>");
    //StreamRoot should be your fully qualified domain name + temp folder for this report instance.
    devInfo.Append("<StreamRoot>" + virtualTempFolder+ "</StreamRoot>");                
    devInfo.Append("</DeviceInfo>");                
}

var result = _reportServerExecutionService.Render(reportFormat, devInfo.ToString(),out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIds);
```

After the render, the `byte[]` should contain your report and once it has been displayed on a web page the embedded images should now be sourced to your temp location that is accessible to your web app.

**EDIT :**

Also, I noticed that you are trying to do some sort of post processing to the content that is returned from `Render().` You do not have to touch that at all. Since you told SSRS to replace the image sources via the `StreamRoot` property then the renderer can handle it from there.

The only steps needed to re-path your report's assets:

1. Let SSRS know where you plan to place the assets it will be referencing in the report.
2. Intercept the report streams and save to an accessible location specified in the step above.

**NOTE :**

Here are some ways to get a virtual and physical temp folder from the context of your web app..

```
//Virtual Temp Folder - MVC                
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Url.Content("~/Temp/");
//Virtual Temp Folder - Non-MVC
VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Temp/"); 
//Physical Temp Folder
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Temp\";
```

Comment: Hi, I am passing "devInfo.ToString()" to my render function but it throws exception.  that "Invalid deviceInfo", I think its because of  wrong physical web root and virtual web root..will u please elaborate what should be "YourPhysicalWebRoot" and "YourVirtualWebRoot".

Comment: I added the way I used to get these folders.

Comment: I changed device info tag like this-<DeviceInfo>  
   <HTMLFragment>True</HTMLFragment>  
</DeviceInfo>  and it works fines.. image is rendering on html...I have same image for all report can I use same  image to replace for evry report...evrtime.it saves new imagd in folder....is there any way to use single.image for report call...

Comment: I am glad it is working. As far as using the same image...since you are intercepting the streamroot I guess you could try to identify the image used by multiple reports and only save it the first time it is not found, however, you might run into an issue with the paths. You can only specify one location for the report, so I don't know how you would specify a location for each report and also a shared location. You would almost have to render all reports into one temp folder, however, then you might get clashes there. It would be interesting to find out if you hack around and make that work.

Comment: You would use HTMLFragment in situations where you need to inject the report content into a div tag or the like. It removes head and body elements  and fits nicely in an existing web page.

Comment: Hi @Ross Bush I have implemented  all this in ASP.NEt MVC 5, One thing I want to Ask you. I want to generate PDF file  on export button click.. I have requirement to genrate pdf,excel and doc file click buttons ..So Can I generate PDF file from rendred html stream?..or I have to render it again from using render function..thank you for your co-operation

Comment: The render stream is only for HTML40 as far as I can tell. When you specify PDF/XLS the byte[]  returned from Render() will contain the PDF/XLS and the images should be embedded. I think that is how ssrs handles images when rendering to those outputs. You certainly want to verify this claim, however. I think PDF and XLS have specific DeviceInfo settings and I am certain that stream root is for HTML only, you will need to look it up though.

Comment: pdf ,excel,doc, will.render image there is no issue i know that...but I want generate pdf excel and doc after report genration of html showed on report div.. I want to generate excel pdf doc file of genrayed report...whether i should again call whole rendering process or I can process on rendered html report for generate pdf or excel file

Comment: The only way to have SSRS render the way you specify is a new call to Render() for each request, regardless of format.

Comment: By the way, if this was helpful and got you past the problem then mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below isway I achieve  render report  using reporting services (ReportExecutionSerivce class and webrefrence of SSRS)

```
 public class ReportManager
    {
        private readonly ReportExecutionService _reportServerExecutionService;

        public ReportManager(string reportServerWsdlUrl, string username, string password, string domain)
        {
            _reportServerExecutionService = new ReportExecutionService
            {
                Url = reportServerWsdlUrl,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password)
            };
        }

        public string Render(string reportDirectory, string reportName, string reportFormat, ParameterValue[] parameters)
        {
            _reportServerExecutionService.ExecutionHeaderValue = new ExecutionHeader();
            _reportServerExecutionService.LoadReport("/GES-MVC/"+reportName, null);
            _reportServerExecutionService.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");


            string encoding;
            string mimeType;
            string extension;
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamIds;


            var result = _reportServerExecutionService.Render(reportFormat, @"<DeviceInfo><StreamRoot>/</StreamRoot><HTMLFragment>True</HTMLFragment></DeviceInfo>", out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIds);
            //Here is logic for image replcaement


            string html = string.Empty;
            html = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
            html = GetReportImages(_reportServerExecutionService, reportFormat, streamIds, html);


            return html;

        }

        public string GetReportImages(ReportExecutionService _reportServerExecutionService, string reportFormat, string[] streamIds, string html)
        {

            if (reportFormat.Equals("HTML4.0") && streamIds.Length > 0)
            {
                string devInfo;
                string mimeType;
                string Encoding;
                string fileExtension = ".jpg";
                string SessionId;
                Byte[] image;



                foreach (string streamId in streamIds)
                {
                    SessionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("}", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("-", "");


                    string reportreplacementname = string.Concat(streamId, "_", SessionId, fileExtension);
                    html = html.Replace(streamId, string.Concat(@"Report\GraphFiles\", reportreplacementname));

                    devInfo = "";
                    image = _reportServerExecutionService.RenderStream(reportFormat, streamId, devInfo, out Encoding, out mimeType);


                    System.IO.FileStream stream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Report\\GraphFiles\\" + reportreplacementname);
                    stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
                    stream.Close();
                    mimeType = "text/html";
                }



            }

            return html;


        }
```

and here I pass required  parameters to class

```
string rprwebserviceurl = exceservice;
                string ReportDirName = "GES-MVC";
                string ReportName = "GES_FWCR";
                string RptFormat = "HTML4.0";
                ParameterValue[] parameters = new ParameterValue[5];
                parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
                parameters[0].Name = "PlantID";
                parameters[0].Value = PlantID;
                parameters[1] = new ParameterValue();
                parameters[1].Name = "FromDateTime";
                parameters[1].Value = Convert.ToString(fromDate); // June
                parameters[2] = new ParameterValue();
                parameters[2].Name = "ToDateTime";
                parameters[2].Value = Convert.ToString(Todate);
                parameters[3] = new ParameterValue();
                parameters[3].Name = "ClientID";
                parameters[3].Value = ClientID;
                parameters[4] = new ParameterValue();
                parameters[4].Name = "SelectedFeeders";
                parameters[4].Value = SelectedFeeders;
                ReportManager rpt = new ReportManager(rprwebserviceurl,RptUserName,RptPassword, "localhost");
                res = rpt.Render(ReportDirName, reportName, RptFormat, parameters);
```